# YouTube videos from verified channels only

Tags: youtube, search, access-control

I would imagine for many YouTube users like me, it is a common nuisance to sift through YouTube's vast content to find the videos uploaded by verified sources (channels). I wonder if there is a way to disable unverified sources. I hoped to see an option within YouTube's settings to restrict to the content from verified sources. But I couldn't find anything like that.

Please let me know if there is any solution for this.